# inner product in minizinc

Tags: minizinc, inner-product

Ιn two Vectors V1(x11, x12) και V2(x21,x22) we can compute their inner product as  V1 • V2.= (x11* x21 + x12 * x22 ).

I try to compute minimum inner product as (x1i*x2j*|i-j|, i.j the places of coordinates at V1, V2.
    Every cooedinate is used once in a sum condition.

```
 I TRIED THIS:


   int : vlen;
set of int : LEN  = 1..vlen;
set of int : VECS = 1..2;
array[VECS,LEN] of -25..25 : vector;
var -600..700 : sumTotal;

constraint exists(i,j,k,l in LEN where i!=k \/ j!=l)(
exists(v,v2 in VECS)(sumTotal=(vector[v,i] * vector[v2,j] * abs(i-j)+vector[v,k] * vector[v2,l] * abs(k-l)
)));
solve minimize sumTotal;
output ["vector1=["]++[" \(vector[1,j])"|j in LEN]++[" ];\nvector2=["]++[" \(vector[2,j])"|j in LEN]++[" ];\nsumTotal=\(sumTotal);"]

for
vlen = 2;
vector = [|-2,3|-4,5|];
```

i expect:

```
vector1 = [-2, 3];
vector2 = [-4, 5];
sumTotal = -22;
----------
==========
```

but i take:

```
vector1=[ -2 3 ];
vector2=[ -4 5 ];
sumTotal=-40;
----------
==========
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are after here. Would you mind adding the dataset, i.e. "vlen" and especially "vector"?

Comment: of course....

vlen = 2;
vector = [|2,3|4,5|];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid I don't understand the meaning of your model, but it does contain some errors in the constraint that should be easy to fix:

- If an array is indexed by `VEC, LEN`, then the second index should always be part of that set.
- `sum` is it's own looping structure; it doesn't need an `forall` expression.

The resulting constraint would be:

```
constraint sumTotal = sum(i,j in LEN)(
    vector[1,i] * vector[2,j] * abs(i,j)
);
```

This still leaves a rather strange model, so you might want to take a look at the following:

- `sumTotal` is your only variable, but it's defined by parameters. It cannot be optimised as it only has 1 solution.
- Should `i` and `j` be able to take the same value? If not, then you should use `i,j in LEN where i < j`.
- Do you expect any results other than `sumTotal`?

Comment: *i run this code:* 
  int : vlen;
  set of int : LEN  = 1..vlen;
  set of int : VECS = 1..2;
  array[VECS,LEN] of int : vector;
  var int: sumTotal;
        
        constraint sumTotal = sum(i,j in LEN)(
            vector[1,i] * vector[2,j] * abs(i-j)
        );
        solve minimize sumTotal;
        output ["vector1=["]++["\(vector[1,j])"|j in LEN]++["];\nvector2=["]++["\(vector[2,j])"|j in LEN]++["];\nsumTotal=\(sumTotal);"];
    
    and i get this result:
        vector1=[23];
        vector2=[45];
  sumTotal=22;
  ----------
   ==========
FALSE FOR MY MODEL :(

Comment: i want my model to compute the minimum sum of x1i * x2j * |i-j| where i.j are coordinates of V1 V2. 
******Every coordinate must be used ONLY once in ONE sum condition****** (How could it be?)

Examples: for vectors (a) [2,3] & [4,5]      -->  2*4 * (|1-1|) + 3*5 (|2 - 2|) = 0.   (sumTotal)
        (b) [-2,3] & [-4,5]    -->  (-2)*(5) * (| 1-2|) + 3 * (-4) * |2-1| = -22 (sumTotal)

expexted results in my model:
vector1 = [2, 3];
vector2 = [4, 5];
sumTotal = 0;
----------
==========

Also, how can i edit my output to looks like the above? ("comma" between 2-2 and 4-5)?